# Rails on start: `split_gem_path': undefined method `split'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I'm running Rails 4.2.4, and using RVM. I get the following error when starting with `rails s`:

```
/home/drew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:50:in `split_gem_path': undefined method `split' for #<Array:0x00000000dc2dc8> (NoMethodError)
  from /home/drew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/path_support.rb:32:in `initialize'
  from /home/drew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:351:in `new'
  from /home/drew/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems.rb:351:in `paths='
  from /data/code/ruby/milligram/bin/spring:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:3:in `load'
  from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following command to start rails:
`bundle exec spring rails s`

Comment: It had to do with rvm and spring not getting along.